# I'm getting "The indexed user_id queried on must be the logged in user" when i query my friends likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

here is my query:

```
FB.api(
       {    
           method: 'fql.multiquery',   
           queries: {    
'friends':'SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2= me()',   
'likes':'SELECT object_id FROM like WHERE user_id in (SELECT uid1 FROM #friends)'
}  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indexed fields cannot be queried except actual user 
for query your friends likes look at [How to get friends likes via Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780586/how-to-get-friends-likes-via-facebook-api/5323807#5323807)

Answer (score 0):

Some FQL queries require that the queried user be logged in. In order to run theis queries without the user being logged in, your app must have the offline_access permission.

Comment: i have access_token of the current user. and  i am trying from console http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery/

Comment: Even if you do have a token for the user, if your app does not have the offline_access permision, the token might have expired already.

Comment: nope authorization is not the problem real part of the question is the indexed fields cannot be queried except actual user .