# Is it possible for a Facebook app to tell how many people like a page?

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

I just got a screenshot of an application, which says that *more of your friends need to like the page in order to see the content*. I am wondering whether this is a scam, because, as far as I know, one cannot tell how many friends like the page.

Does Facebook API provide a way to track the number of friend likes? or generally, how many people like the page?

[image: like page]

Comment: I think this question does not really belong here. At least not as it is now.

Comment: I edited the title slightly because I think this is essentially a good question. Feel free to roll back if you don't like it

Comment: @Baszz, I am a bit confused why is that the case?

Comment: @Guy: look at this page: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: @Baszz, so the question is essentially asking whether there is a way to tell how many people/friends like the page. Which will inevitably require programming. How is that off-topic, buddy? : )

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the app requests permission to see your friends list and you add the app (and in doing so grant permission).

Many apps know if your friends are online and how you rank in points in comparison.  Look at nearly any Zynga game and you'll see that list/ranking at the bottom.

Comment: Can I tell how many of my friends like the page, though? Although they are not connected to the app?

Comment: Yes.  If you go to a page, on the right side of the page's wall is a section called "You and [page name]". People listed there are your friends that like the page.

Comment: I think this gives you what you want - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780586/how-to-get-friends-likes-via-facebook-api