# Get all friends and their likes using the Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm just getting started with a project and wondered if someone can let me know if it's possible to:

A) Get a list of all friends for an authorised Facebook account via the API

B) Get all of the likes for each friend using the API

I saw this code suggested on another question:

```
FB.api("/likes?ids=533856945,841978743")

FB.api("me/friends",{
  fields:'id',
  limit:10
},function(res){
  var l=''
  $.each(res.data,function(idx,val){
     l=l+val.id+(idx<res.data.length-1?',':'')
  })
  FB.api("likes?ids="+l,function(res){
      console.log(res);
  })
})
```

But I'm struggling to understand the logic of this as it looks like you need to know the `ids` to get the likes.

Also is there a limit to the number of likes returned?  I read something about it only returning the last `X` number of likes for each user.

Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, to your first question. It's possible. I'm not sure about the second part of your question. I'd imagine it would be possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get friends likes via Facebook API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780586/how-to-get-friends-likes-via-facebook-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch all the friends for an authorized user with the friends.get API call.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/friends.get/

Once you have the list of friends, you can loop through the list and fetch their likes by using the graph API's "likes" call.

Graph API Documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Sample "likes" request: https://graph.facebook.com/put_a_fb_user_id_here/likes

Comment: excellent - that's what I was after. One thing I did notice was that Facebook say that their REST API is being depricated - is there another method that doesn't use REST?

Comment: also, the likes request only returns likes for facebook pages but not links to pages on other sites that the user has liked.  Do you know of a request to get the links that the user has liked too?